# Magento /admin panel doesn't work

Tags: magento

After I copied my magento installation on a new domain. The admin panel doesn't work. I checked the .htaccess, baseurls and tried a lot of other things, still the 404 error page.

The version of my installion is 1.9.

Comment: are you sure your Frontend is working ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following step.

1. delete cache folder from var
2. if you domain name changed then open your database and select core_config_data and set secure and insecure web url to your domain specific url
3. if you have still further problem for css and js and you have to make merge css and js flag to 0 which is also found in core_config_data

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I hope sagar helped you to get rid of the problem.

to my opinion this issue happens due to improper setup of the core stores in magento.

what I did to resolve the issue to check the core_store tables.  Check if store admin is active.

Make it active and your 404 problem will go away.

Thanks me later !!!